# Question about Kadets Klee norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a book that claims the following: If $C$ is a closed bounded convex subset of the sphere in a space with the Kadets Klee property, then $C$ is weakly compact.

I'm not sure why this is true. If $(x_n)_n$ is any sequence in $C$. If it has a weakly converging subsequence converging to $x$, then $x\in C$ since $C$ is also weakly closed. Then $||x_{n_k}||\to ||x||$ since the sequence and $x$ are in the sphere, and this would imply norm convergence. But I don't see why $(x_n)_n$ has a weakly converging subsequence to begin with.

Comment: what is Kadets Klee property?

Comment: If you converge weakly and the norms converge, then the sequence converges in norm